# How to write a simple test case for users by using drupal_mail() function?

Tags: 7, emails, testing

I have written a custom module for sending email to registered users.
And I want simple test case for that users email module.

In this module I am taking a user from database and selected users preferred language and sending emails.

Same as I want *.test* file, I don't know how to write *.test* file for this module.

I am using the [SimpleTest](https://www.drupal.org/project/simpletest) module, version 7.x-2.x (in Drupal 7).

Comment: i want admin can send an emails to register users by using cron in every one day,i want that test cases.

Answer (score 0):

Finding documentation about the SimpleTest module has never been obvious (also because using the [Read Documentation](http://drupal.org/node/291740) link on the module's project page causes a 404-error ...).

Here are some pointers I've found so far:

- The article about [A Drupal Module Developer's Guide to SimpleTest](https://www.lullabot.com/articles/a-drupal-module-developers-guide-to-simpletest) (not sure right now how accurate it still is, but at least it outlines the main steps). Note this part in it: "*... make a simple list of things that your module does. This list will translate directly to SimpleTest tests.*".
- The article about "[How to: Write Automated Tests for Drupal](http://cwgordon.com/how-to-write-automated-tests-for-drupal)", in one of it's comment near the bottom it says:

  > As of now, it's the same API for the Drupal 7 core module and the Drupal 6 contributed module (http://drupal.org/project/simpletest), so this tutorial should work for both.
- The [SimpleTest Example](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/examples/tree/simpletest_example) that comes with the [Examples](https://www.drupal.org/project/examples) module, and also includes a [.test file](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/examples/tree/simpletest_example/simpletest_example.test) (something you refer to in your question also). In other words: the best available documentation on this is "read the source".

**Be aware**:

- Make sure to you take into account what's written in [API.txt](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/simpletest/tree/API.txt?h=7.x-2.x), i.e.:

  > ... Provides a reference of the API changes between SimpleTest 7.x-1.x included with Drupal 7 core and SimpleTest 7.x-2.x.
  >
  > Modules that provided 2.x compatible tests are required to add the following attribute to their info file: `testing_api = 2.x`.

  So SimpleTest requires a version number in the `.info` file, which you specify by adding that `testing_api = 2.x` in your .info file.
- This module has *Maintenance status*: Unknown, *Development status*: Unknown

**Note:** As of D7, there is the [PHP Unit Testing Framework](https://www.drupal.org/project/testing) module (namespace = `testing`). Refer to the Community Documentation about [Testing (D7 and D8) / SimpleTest (D6)](https://www.drupal.org/simpletest) for quite some more details on all this.

Comment: i want admin can send an emails to register users by using cron in every one day,i want that test cases.

Comment: my requirement is when i am in admin,and if i am run the email custom module through simple testing,all emails are automatically send to registerred users.

Comment: Pierre can please  help me on this problem,how can i write .test file?